Importing an m3u8 stream into kinesis video streams via gstreamer - audio out of sync
I'm trying to push an m3u8 stream into kinesis video stream in order to use rekognition for some analysis.
However the audio is out of sync by a few seconds, and I'm unable to work out what I need to do in order to fix it.
I'm using the following gstreamer command:
gst-launch-1.0 multiqueue name="mqueue" max-size-bytes=0 max-size-time=0 \
  souphttpsrc location="<URL_GOES_HERE>" \
  ! hlsdemux name="mdemux" connection-speed=4294967 \
  mdemux.src_0 ! mqueue.sink_0 mqueue.src_0 ! tsdemux name=demux parse-private-sections=TRUE ! multiqueue max-size-bytes=0 max-size-time=0 ! video/x-h264 ! h264parse ! kvssink name=sink stream-name="audio-video-file" access-key="${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}" secret-key="${AWS_SECRET_KEY}" aws-region="${AWS_REGION}" retention-period=2 \
  mdemux.src_1 ! mqueue.sink_1 mqueue.src_1 ! aacparse ! multiqueue max-size-bytes=8388608 max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=10000000000 ! audio/mpeg ! sink.

A few things:

I set the connection speed on the hlsdemux as it looked like there were a number of video streams, and without the connection speed, gstreamer would exit not knowing which one to choose
I generated a dot file from using playbin to try and work out how that was playing the stream. From there, I got the values for the multiqueue
I've tried replacing the multiqueue with queue and that didn't seem to work either

